# How to use prefetch_to_device with Keras model?

Tags: c#, python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

My training under 1% GPU, but nearly 50% of CPU with `tensorflow-gpu==1.12`.

I took a look at the device placement logging, and it seems, that `Dataset`-based pipelines are run entirely on CPU, which seems to be the cause of the problem.

Here is an excerpt from the code, prior to my attempt to move all data to GPU:

```
train = train
    .skip(validationSampleCount)
    .cache()
    //.shuffle(buffer_size: sampleCount - validationSampleCount)
    .batch(batch_size: 4096);

model.fit(train, ...);
```

This works fine.

For moving data to the GPU, I found `tf.data.experimental.prefetch_to_device`, which I tried to use like this:

```
dynamic gpuPrefetchOp = experimental.prefetch_to_device(
    "/gpu:0",
    (validationSampleCount + 1) / 4096);

dynamic prefetched = train.apply(gpuPrefetchOp);

model.fit(prefetched, ...);
```

Unfortunately, this fails with `AttributeError`: `_PrefetchToDeviceIterator` object has no attribute `shape`.

How do I feed a `Dataset`, prefetched into GPU with `prefetch_to_device`, to a Keras `Sequential` model?